# Detect data in txt files, string parse and output as csv file

Tags: python, string, csv, string-parsing

this is my code. I am working on use code detected a bunch of text files in a folder and then string parse the data output as csv files. Could you please give me some hint on how to do this? I am hard struggled.

The first step for my code is detect where the data is in txt files. I found that all the data starts with 'Read', then I found which line the data starts in each files. After that I am struggled on how to export the data output to csv files.

```
import os
import argparse
import csv
from typing import List


def validate_directory(path):
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        return path
    else:
        raise NotADirectoryError(path)


def get_data_from_file(file) -> List[str]:
    ignore_list = ["Read Segment", "Read Disk", "Read a line", "Read in"]
    data = []
    with open(file, "r", encoding="latin1") as f:
        try:
            lines = f.readlines()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Unable to process {file}: {e}")
            return []
        for line_number, line in enumerate(lines, start=1):
            if not any(variation in line for variation in ignore_list):
                if line.strip().startswith("Read ") and not line.strip().startswith("Read ("): # TODO: fix this with better regex
                    data.append(f'Found "Read" at line {line_number} in {file}')
                    print(f'Found "Read" at {file}:{line_number}')
                    print(lines[line_number-1])
    return data


def list_read_data(directory_path: str) -> List[str]:
    total_data = []
    for root, _, files in os.walk(directory_path):
        for file_name in files:
            if file_name.endswith(".txt"):
                data = get_data_from_file(os.path.join(root, file_name))
                total_data.extend(data)

    return total_data


def write_results_to_csv(output_file: str, data: List[str]):
    with open(output_file, "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(["Results"])
        for line in data:
            writer.writerow([line])


def main(directory_path: str, output_file: str):
    data = list_read_data(directory_path)
    write_results_to_csv(output_file, data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="Process the 2020Model folder for input data."
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--directory", type=validate_directory, help="folder to be processed"
    )
    parser.add_argument("--output", type=str, help="Output file name (e.g., outputfile.csv)", default="outputfile.csv")

    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(os.path.abspath(args.directory), args.output)
```

Below is my ideal csv output data:

| 1985 | 1986 | 1986 | 1987 | 1988 | 1989 | 1990 | 1991 | 1992 | 1993 | 1994 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 37839 | 36962 | 37856 | 41971 | 40838 | 44640.87 | 42826.34 | 44883.03 | 43077.59 | 45006.49 | 46789 |

Could you please give me some hint on:

- where to put the string parse?
- how to output as CSV file.

Below is a sample txt file:

```
Select Year(2007-2025)
Read TotPkSav
/2007     2008     2009     2010     2011     2012     2013     2014     2015     2016     2017     2018     2019     2020     2021     2022     2023     2024     2025 
   00       27       53       78      108      133      151      161      169      177      186      195      205      216      229      242      257      273      288
```

Comment: Hi  I've read your post, and I don't understand what the text file looks like such that you need the ignore-list and then checking for a certain kind "Read".  The text you shared looks like plain CSV. Can you edit the question and include more of the text? Thanks :)

Comment: The code in *get_data_from_file()* isn't going to work for the text file layout you've shown in the question. In fact, as @ZachYoung has pointed out, it looks like CSV

Comment: Hi Zach and DarkKnight, thanks for watching this question, I already uploaded the sample txt files. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all your files look like those 4 lines, then I'd recommend just turning the file into a list of lines up front, and not try to step/iterate over the lines.  I also recommend just using glob and recursive=True and avoid trying to walk the tree.

Because it reads the file inside the for-loop, any files with bad properties can be skipped by just `continue`-ing to the next file in the loop:

```py
all_rows: list[list[str]] = []

for fname in glob.glob("**/*.txt", recursive=True):
    with open(fname, encoding="iso-8859-1") as f:
        print(f"reading {fname}")
        lines = [x.strip() for x in list(f)]

        if len(lines) != 4:
            print(f'skipping {fname} with too few lines"')
            continue

        line2 = lines[1]
        if line2[:4] != "Read" or line2[:6] == "Read (":
            print(f'skipping {fname} with line2 = "{line2}"')
            continue

        line3, line4 = lines[2:4]

        if line3[0] == "/":
            line3 = line3[1:]

        header = [x for x in line3.split(" ") if x]
        data = [x for x in line4.split(" ") if x]
      
        all_rows.append(header)
        all_rows.append(data)

with open("output.csv", "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["Result"])
    writer.writerows(all_rows)
```

I mocked up a few more files and spread them throughout my tree:

```
 - .
 - a
    input3.txt
 - b
    foo.txt
   input1.txt
   input2.txt
   main.py
```

When I run that program from the root of that tree, I get:

```
reading input1.txt
reading input2.txt
skipping input2.txt with line2 = "Read (TotPkSav)"
reading a/input3.txt
reading b/foo.txt
skipping b/foo.txt with too few lines"
```

and output.csv looks like:

```
| Result |
|--------|
| 2007 | 2008 | 2009 | 2010 | 2011 | 2012 | 2013 | 2014 | 2015 | 2016 | 2017 | 2018 | 2019 | 2020 | 2021 | 2022 | 2023 | 2024 | 2025 |
| 00   | 27   | 53   | 78   | 108  | 133  | 151  | 161  | 169  | 177  | 186  | 195  | 205  | 216  | 229  | 242  | 257  | 273  | 288  |
| 2099 | 2098 | 2009 | 2010 | 2011 | 2012 | 2013 | 2014 | 2015 | 2016 | 2017 | 2018 | 2019 | 2020 | 2021 | 2022 | 2023 | 2024 | 2025 |
| 00   | 27   | 53   | 78   | 108  | 133  | 151  | 161  | 169  | 177  | 186  | 195  | 205  | 216  | 229  | 242  | 257  | 273  | 288  |
```

Comment: @mmmm, hey. If this helped you, please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark at the top-left of the answer. Thanks!